# Tomcat 7 servlet needs to force a close of a long-lasting NIO connection

Tags: tomcat, connection, nio

I have a Tomcat 7 servlet accepting connections from remote clients, and keeping those connections open for hours or days if possible. So, we are using the NIO connector.
The bandwidth on the physical connections may be expensive, so traffic is to be kept to an absolute minimum, therefore we have programmed the remote clients to test the connection with a very infrequent ping.

Occasionally, the servlet is told the connection is closed, but it seems that the remote clients are not told. The clients don't find out until they do a ping, at which time they can establish a new connection. We need to reduce the length of time the clients are not connected, without using more pings.

One way that works is to shut down the Tomcat server. The clients know they are disconnected immediately. Obviously we don't want to be shutting down Tomcat - my point is there must be some kind of signal making it across the normally-quiet connection.

How can I force Tomcat to send this signal? Please don't respond that I can't unless you can tell me why, with specifics, partly because I can't believe it, and mostly because I don't want to believe it. It seems strange - like not being able to hang-up the phone on someone.

Alternate question #1 - can a servlet recover a connection it has been told is closed?

Alternate question #2 - can anyone think of anything else that might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

- I'm surprised the clients are unaware that the connection has been dropped.  Are you certain that an exception is not being swallowed somewhere client side?
- With days long connections, I'd start to look at what is happening on the TCP layer.  You've not mentioned any diagnostic or information...

  - Have you attempted to determine if the there is an underlying TCP/IP connection still present for these problem client/server connections?
  - How stable is the network between client and server?
  - Are their potentially misbehaving network devices, like proxies or routers involved?
- I don't really see the benefit of using the NIO connector in this context of long lived connections.  Many requests per second?  Yes.  But just for long lived connections?  No.

  - In the past I've had a bizarre issue with the NIO connector and a servlet protocol gateway (OpenAMF) that magically went away by using the default HTTP connector.
  - Test the other two connectors (HTTP, native ARP), benchmark them.
- I would also consider ditching any TCP-based protocol (like HTTP) in favor of some UDP-based approach.  That way your connections would be state-less and, with a bespoke tuned payload, the packets very small.

Comment: Stu - thanks for your help. I'm surprised the clients are unaware too. It appears that Tomcat is not passing on info the servlet is aware of. I am not certain of what is happening client side. There is a reputable cellphone service provider between Tomcat and the clients, and I have no way of knowing what it is doing.

Comment: (me again) Also, I would do more diagnostics on the TCP/IP if I knew how - networks are not my strong suit. We have used WireShark, but I don't really know what I am looking at. I thought I had to use NIO for server-push - can you point me to any example code or tutorials that would get me up to speed?

Comment: @Dave: This is all over a mobile network? I'd really suggest a different approach, like UDP or some sort of limited duration long polling.  Remember that Tomcat is, at the end of the day, an HTTP server.  HTTP is stateless, request/response protocol.  It doesn't sound like what you are trying to do suites HTTP very well.  *"The right tool for the right job."*  As for network diagnostic tools, start with simpler utilities like netstat.  Wireshare is indeed heavy stuff.

Comment: Stu; Thanks - I am reading up on UDP. Unfortunately, I don't have real control over the client - it uses HTTP, and everything is working fine except for this one issue, and if I am prepared to shut down Tomcat every once in a while (of course I don't want to) then it works 100%.

Comment: If you don't have control over the client then you probably should be careful about making diagnostic assumptions on it.  Go with the netstat checks, find out what the state of the connection is on a tcp/ip level, if any.  Do you have control over the server TCP/IP stack?  You could probably tune down timeout values with the aim of forcing broken connections to close, or something else positive.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I am accepting this answer as the best available, that is, I need to get more info about the network traffic.  Unfortunately, the project has wrapped up so I can not spend any more time on this issue, even though it is not fully resolved.  For anyone else looking into this, I think there might be a work-around using JMX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this old question as we've seen the same issue with HTTP connections (or any TCP connections) held open for tens of minutes with no traffic **across a firewall**. If there really is no firewall, then my answer doesn't apply.

You can confirm this theory with simultaneous tcpdump/wireshark on client and server and some patience.

If there is a firewall, then you'll need to make sure that that the 'ping' packets occur more often than the firewall's idle TCP connection time out in order to keep the connection alive. Think twice before increasing the firewall time out, the firewall may not be up to it, as I'll explain.

A firewall between your clients and the server may be performing NAT or some packet inspection. These features require resources on the firewall and there is a limit to the number of connections the firewall will track. So by default it will 'silently close' these connections after an idle time out, to conserve resources.

I say silently because the firewall aften won't send out any packets to either side, until either the client or the server send out traffic. At this point the firewall will usually respond with a RST packet. We traced this using tcpdump from both a client and server. It showed the firewall sending this RST packet as if from the side of the connection. However the tcpdump on the other side confirmed this packet was not sent. It had to be the firewall.

Increasing the size of the idle timeout on the firewall can lead to more problems, as the firewall may not be able to handle the number of connections. This can lead to a total firewall reset where you may see all tcp sockets across the firewall.

As you have to use TCP, then avoid any firewall feature that would require connection tracking on the firewall (NAT, accounting, packet inspection). Or make sure that you have a firewall with enough resources to track all the connections.